# c#, printing items in list returns empty when list.add(Console.ReadLine)

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, console.writeline, console.readline

The console doesn't write the items in the list. I am trying to add input from user to a list then write to the screen. So once i add input to the list i would want it to print to the screen.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

 switch (userInput)
        {

            case "Add":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Fullname: ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    list.Add(Console.ReadLine());

                    display();
                    break;
                }


            case "List":
                {

                    foreach (string item in list)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                    display();
                    break;
                }

        }
```

Comment: Too many calls to Console.Readline in case of "Add"

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to a variable and then add

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
list.Add(line);
```

Comment: Still doesn't print the item in the list

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

you delete all the elements in the ArrayList.

You didn't post how do you get to the "List" section after insertion the elements...

also you sholud delete the first

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is to create a new list. Then i add elements to list.

Comment: But how do you enter to the List section?

Comment: Case "List" shows how to view each item in the list

Comment: But after you enter Add, you adding an element to the list, and after that becuase the "Break" statment you exit from the switch-case...